# Doubt in discontinuities of a monotonic function.

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

We know that

> the set of discontinuities($E$ say) of a monotonic function $f$ is at most countable.

In its proof as given in Rudin(2ed), for every $x\in E$ we associate a rational number $r(x)$ such that $$f(x-)<r(x)<f(x+)$$
Since $f$ is monotonic both $f(x-),f(x+)$ exists and hence we can find such a rational number $r(x)$. Thus we have a $1-1$ correspondence between the set E and a subset of the set of rational numbers. Hence it is atmost countable.

> **Doubt:**  suppose $f(x-),f(x+)$ does not exist, and let $f(x-)=-\infty$ and $f(x+)=+\infty$ then here also we can find such a $r(x)$ and put $E$ in $1-1$ correspondence with a subset of rational numbers.

I couldn't find any contradiction, that when $f$ is not monotonic the above argument cannot be applied.

Comment: How does your proposed 1-1 correspondence work, if there happen to be uncountably many discontinuities? Example: let $f$ be the characteristic function of the rationals, in which case $f$ is discontinuous everywhere. How do you define $r(x)$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are dealing with an increasing function here. We cannot have
$f(x-)=-\infty$ since $f(x-)\ge f(y)$ for any $y<x$.

For non-monotonic functions there are two obstructions to
this argument. A discontinuity may not be simple: either or
both of $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ may fail to exist. Also, even if
they did the proof that the $r(x)$ are distinct collapses.

Comment: if $f$ is not monotone how the argument fails?

Comment: please give one example where i can see this clearly

Comment: @ArunBadajena A clear example is $1_{\Bbb Q}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yeah, that is cool.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

See this for the required counterexample.

Comment: thanks!! I got it.